# Passing object to another view and changing its value in SwiftUI

Tags: view, swiftui, parameter-passing, immutability

I have a problem with following task. I have a struct created of an activity and a class which is an array of Activity objects.

```
struct Activity: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let description: String
    var amount: Int
}

class Activities: ObservableObject {
    @Published var activities = [Activity]() {
}
```

In my main view I have a list of these activities and using NavigationLink we can go to each activity and see the description and the number of times we did it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var activities = Activities()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(activities.activities, content: { activity in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ActivityView(activity: activity),
                        label: {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(activity.name)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                Text("\(activity.amount)")
                            }
                        })
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that in this detail view I want to be able to increment the number of times we did the activity but I get an error: **Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'self' is immutable**

```
struct ActivityView: View {
    var activity: Activity
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(activity.name)
        Text(activity.description)
        Text("\(activity.amount)")
        Button(action: {
            print(activity.amount)
            self.activity.amount += 1
        }, label: {
            Text("Button")
        })
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use binding for that like

```
struct ActivityView: View {
    @Binding var activity: Activity
...
```

and update parent to pass bound value

```
    ForEach(Array(activities.activities.enumerated()), id: \.1, content: { i, activity in
        NavigationLink(
            destination: ActivityView(activity: self.$activities[i]),
```